# Variable Scope and Looping Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, loops, scope

I have a loop

```
suburb_gps = [-35.44454, 127.4323423]

tradies_in_area.delete_if do |tradie|
  gps_coor = suburb_gps

  tradie.tradie_locations.first.radius < (Geography.distance(tradie.tradie_locations.first.get_lat_and_lon, gps_coor) / 1000)
end
```

In the loop you notice I assign the variable `gps_coor` to `suburb_gps`. Then I use `gps_coor` in the `distance` method which determines the distance between the two coordinates. My main problem is after the first loop the `suburb_gps` variable changes, and keeps changing after every loop. I have no idea why it's screwing up. The `get_lat_and_lon` is an instance method for my model class

```
def get_lat_and_lon
  [self.latitude, self.longitude]
end
```

I have no idea why the `suburb_gps` variable changes after every loop. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Below are some of the things the suburb_gps equals after the loops

```
2013-11-06T21:12:10.789459+00:00 app[web.1]: [-7.297875028610691e-286, 4.08087004920688e-285]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.789459+00:00 app[web.1]: [-1.2737194764833194e-287, 7.122461870468308e-287]

2013-11-06T21:12:10.789459+00:00 app[web.1]: [-2.223059861141241e-289, 1.2431041048742584e-288]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.789749+00:00 app[web.1]: [-3.87997140458426e-291, 2.16962595751127e-290]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.789897+00:00 app[web.1]: [-1.181906878110669e-294, 6.609058610793502e-294]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.789749+00:00 app[web.1]: [-6.771827589322435e-293, 3.786711649530626e-292]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.789897+00:00 app[web.1]: [-2.062816647499847e-296, 1.1534983321562906e-295]

2013-11-06T21:12:10.790298+00:00 app[web.1]: [-6.283698846544718e-300, 3.51375685669721e-299]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.790298+00:00 app[web.1]: [-1.0967123407597525e-301, 6.132662626389288e-301]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.790298+00:00 app[web.1]: [-3.6002942363823585e-298, 2.0132343812390454e-297]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.790298+00:00 app[web.1]: [-1.914124129351169e-303, 1.0703515474449596e-302]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.790298+00:00 app[web.1]: [-3.340776834904773e-305, 1.8681158656730845e-304]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.790579+00:00 app[web.1]: [-5.8307555343443306e-307, 3.260477266473944e-306]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.790579+00:00 app[web.1]: [-1.017658819531899e-308, 5.690606348639485e-308]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.790579+00:00 app[web.1]: [-1.77614970627906e-310, 9.93198172186515e-310]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.790579+00:00 app[web.1]: [-3.09996603829e-312, 1.733457822944e-311]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.790942+00:00 app[web.1]: [-1.648121e-317, 9.216062e-317]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.790579+00:00 app[web.1]: [-5.410461407e-314, 3.02545464546e-313]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.790942+00:00 app[web.1]: [-9.44303657e-316, 5.280414494e-315]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.790942+00:00 app[web.1]: [-5.02e-321, 2.8073e-320]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.790942+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.0, 1.0e-323]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.790942+00:00 app[web.1]: [-2.8765e-319, 1.608505e-318]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.790942+00:00 app[web.1]: [-9.0e-323, 4.9e-322]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.790942+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.0, 0.0]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.791683+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.0, 0.0]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.791683+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.0, 0.0]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.791683+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.0, 0.0]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.791683+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.0, 0.0]
2013-11-06T21:12:10.792060+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.0, 0.0]
```

The output continues to print `[-0.0, 0.0]` till the loop is done.

Comment: What does suburb_gps keep changing to? Any obvious pattern? Output would be helpful.

Comment: I can give hundreds of outputs. I'll post some in a second.

Comment: "I assign gps_coor to suburb_gps."; No, you assign `suburb_gps` to `gps_coor`.

Comment: Where is this method - `Geography.distance` - defined?  And does problem go away if you write `gps_coor = suburb_gps.dup`?  I suspect that the distance method is altering the contents of the array that you're passing in.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking. I'll test with the dup method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making `gps_coor` a *reference* to the same array `suburb_gps` references. From that point, both variables point to the same object, and modifying one (which presumably happens in `Geography.distance`?) modifies the other.

You need to [`clone`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-clone) or [`dup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-dup) the array instead:

```
gps_coor = suburb_gps.clone
```

Typically, this would be done inside the method that needs to modify its input array. Really, you should be adding the `.clone` inside `Geography.distance`, and just using `suburb_gps` as the argument to that method.

Comment: +1 - and ideally not change the value in a method with an unassuming name like 'distance'.  Better yet, dup the value inside the `distance` method (assuming you have access to this) to avoid this in the future.